# Make a SQL Alchemy Expression return value from a different Table's column for filtering

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

How can you use the sql alchemy expression language to make sqlalchemy's `filter_by` look through a hybrid property that returns a value from a column in another table?

### Example Code

(Using flask-sqlalchemy so you'll see stuff like `Device.query.get(203)`

```
class Service(Model):
    id = Column(Integer)
    client_id = Column(Integer)


class Device(Mode):
    id = Column(Integer)
    owner = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def client_id(self):
        return Service.query.get(self.owner).client_id

    @client_id.expression
    def client_id(self):
        # ???


# Make this return a useful query
Device.query.filter(client_id=124)
```

### SQL QUERY

This is the SQL that returns the proper values.

```
SELECT service.clientid FROM device INNER JOIN service ON device.owner = service.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the desired `sql`, but should produce the same result:

```
@client_id.expression
def client_id(cls):
    return (
        select([Service.client_id])
        .where(Service.id == cls.owner)
        .as_scalar()
    )
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!  One question.  Why as scalar?

Comment: Without it, for some backends (postgresql) the generated query would not be correct. But basically it is to indicate that we expect single value from this `select` as opposed to table-like result.